# Scala: Convert nearly identical case classes with value of different type

Tags: scala, default-parameters

Say I have a case class of:

```
case class car1 (
  var wheels: Map[String, String] = Map[String, String](),
  var tire: String = "",
  var window: String = ""
) {}
```

and I simply want to convert an instance of it into another case class with a single difference in the type of one variable `wheels`, with all other values the same:

```
case class car2 (
  var wheels: Array[(String, String)],
  var tire: String = "",
  var window: String = ""
) {}
```

What is the best way in Scala to:
1. Abstract all boilerplate default values into a single structure
2. convert between the two classes such that a conversion changes the type of the `wheels` value

I want to convert an instance of `car1` into `car2` such that a standard conversion function is applied to wheels.

Comment: it is `Array[(String, String)]`

Answer (score 2):

*2.* Try

```
case class car1 (
                  var wheels: Map[String, String] = Map[String, String](),
                  var tire  : String              = "",
                  var window: String              = ""
                ) {
  def toCar2: car2 = car2(wheels.toArray, tire, window)
}
```

*1.* Try

```
def default[A](implicit factory: Factory[_, A]): A = factory.newBuilder.result()

case class car1 (
                  var wheels: Map[String, String] = default,
                  var tire  : String              = default,
                  var window: String              = default
                ) {
  def toCar2: car2 = car2(wheels.toArray, tire, window)
}

case class car2 (
                  var wheels: Array[(String, String)] = default,
                  var tire  : String                  = default,
                  var window: String                  = default
                ) {}
```

Scala 2.13.

Answer (score 2):

I would add an `apply` function in the `companion object` of `car2`:

```
object car2 {
  def apply(car1: car1): car2 =
     car2(car1.wheels.toArray, car1.tire, car1.window)
}
```

Usage:

```
car2(car1(Map("x" -> "a"), "conti", "glass"))
```